# Как заменить имя объекта в json-файле

Tags: php, json, регулярные-выражения

Есть json-файл сохранённый в строке вида {"Org1":[{"a":1,"b":2},{...}...]} (название файла file.json)

Более наглядный вид:

```
{
"Org1": [
{
"a": 1,
"b": 2
},
{
"a": 12,
"b": 345
},
{
"a": 12364,
"b": -1
}
],
"Org2": [
]
}
```

Нужно изменить "Org1" на "Org123", не меняя порядка.
Значения "Org1" и  "Org123" в виде переменных "$SchoolOldName" и "$SchoolName" соответственное.

Проблема:

```
$file = "file.json";
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents("$file"), true);
$json = str_replace($SchoolOldName, $SchoolName, $json);
file_put_contents("$file", json_encode($json));
```

В таком варианте ничего не работает.

Если делать без json_decode/json_encode -- просто через file_get_contents, то всё работает, пока "Org1" не будет написано русскими символами. Тогда без json_encode название будет вида "\u0410\u0432\u0430\u043b\u043e\u043d" и str_replace не сработает.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как перекодировать строку json в русский текст (чтобы она и осталась строкой, а не массивом)? Или же как сделать рабочий вариант замены значения с помощью json_decode?

Comment: [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.str-replace.php)

Comment: Зачем задавать новый вопрос, который на 90% совпадает с предыдущим? Можно было старый подредактировать.

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский Спасибо! Заменил `$jsonLectures = preg_replace("/\"$SchoolOldName\"/m", "\"$SchoolName\"", $jsonLectures);` на 
`$jsonLectures = str_replace($SchoolOldName, $SchoolName, $jsonLectures);`

Теперь json-файл не ломается, но русские значения всё равно не меняются почему-то...

Comment: @Ya_O что значит не меняются? русские значения в json не меняется на русское значение из переменной? ошибки есть?

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский Да. Русские значения в json не меняются на русские значения переменной (это если без json_encode/decode. Если с ними, то вообще не работает).

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/282102e6671d5e37ed206355a46eb16d20da1116   ...... может что-то у тебя с кодировкой файла....

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский В этом примере ведь тоже "Привет" на "Пока" нигде не заменилось.

Comment: потому что я в переменную её не положил)) http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4671b64d2f1f904f406d796fe3588baba4daaead